# Hard rock, great meal / Flowing, pierces the mountains / Empty, a heat trap

Tags: riddle, haiku

> Hard rock, great meal
> Flowing, pierces the mountains
> Empty, a heat trap
>
> Important to you
> With me, you die in minutes
> Without me, just days.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are

> water.

---

Hard rock, great meal
Flowing, pierces the mountains
Empty, a heat trap

> Flowing water in rivers can erode rocks and mountains. Water can absorb a lot of heat.

Important to you
With me, you die in minutes
Without me, just days.

> Water is necessary for life. Drowning takes minutes, while death by dehydration takes several days.

Comment: You did it! YAY!! (But the explanation for the first stanza is incomplete.)

Comment: `Empty` is used in contrast to `Flowing`, so I'd say it refers to a desert, which are usually (at least as most people think of them) pretty toasty.

Comment: @feelinferrety Not what I intended as the reason, but that fits too. The first stanza has a theme...

Comment: Is it supposed to be about mirages? Empty a heat trap.

Comment: @Z.Dailey No. It has a theme...

Comment: The theme might be states of matter and "empty" would be humid which can also make you feel hot.

Comment: Ice is like hard rock or a meal if you talk about icecream.
Liquid water pierces the mountains and steam is obviously hot.

Comment: stackErr Shkeil You're on the right track...